# Запуск Atollic TrueSTUDIO на Linux. Ошибка библиотеки libc6-i386

Tags: linux, stm32

При попытке установить Atollic TrueSTUDIO, скачанного с [официального сайта](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/truestudio.html) на Ubuntu 20.04 LTS выдается ошибка. Видимо связана с какой-то 32 битной библиотекой.

Продолжение установки ни к чему не приводят, как описано на скрине:

[image: Ошибка связанная с libc6-i386]

Попытки исправить ситуацию по [совету](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451939/cant-install-libc6-package) приводят к тому, что нужно установить 4 ГБ непонятно чего с кучей файлов с javasript.

Как исправить ситуацию? В Embedded разработке разбираюсь еще плохо.

Цель установки - работа с микроконтроллерами stm32.

Comment: выполните sudo apt install -f после попробуй произвести установку еще раз

Comment: К сожалению ошибка повторилась.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в отсутствии в репозитории пакета libwebkitgtk-3.0

Установка пакета

```
sudo su
echo 'deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main universe' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tmp.list   
apt update    
apt install libwebkitgtk-3.0-0    
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tmp.list    
exit
```

Проверил на Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Антон, после установки указанных пакетов, установка Atollic вновь неудалась. Ошибка в терминале: Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Failed to fix 32-bit libraries.
Please install 32-bit libraries manually, then run install.sh again.

Comment: Попытался выполнить sudo apt-get install libc6-i386. Получаю следующее сообщение: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить "sudo apt install -f" Это должно или пофиксить зависимости или произвести удаление ошибочных пакетов, после  "sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386" это добавит поддержку архитектуры i386.

Comment: Он всё-равно ссылается на неудовлетворенные зависимости libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is to be installed.
Нигде в сети не нашёл ответ как истранить сие зависимости. Попробую создать новый вопрос. Возможно, у меня попросту проблемы с самой ОС

Comment: Посмотрите, какая версия libc6 у вас установлена и установлена ли вообще: dpkg -l | grep libc6

Comment: Выдан результат: ii  libc6:amd64 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 ii  2.31-0ubuntu9.2 libc6-dbg:amd64 ii  libc6-dev:amd64 2.31-0ubuntu9.2. Почему-то libc6 везде выделено красным

Comment: sudo apt install -f && sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt install libc6-i386

Comment: Увы, к сожалению, результат вновь уперся в зависимости: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Есть одно [решение] (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023962/how-to-install-libc6i386-on-16-04-4-64bit) но здесь при установке требуется 4 Гб и среди пакетов перечислены пакеты с именами типа Crypto, Client, Javascript и так далее. Не установлю ли я так троянов всяких?

Comment: Нет не натяните ничего. Все с офф репозиториев

Comment: Было ошибкой запустить это. Исчез проводник, теперь не запускается система обновлений, не могу указывать репозитории. При попытке установить любой пакет теперь выходит информация о нарушении зависимостей.

Comment: Попробуйте по инструкции https://losst.ru/neudovletvorennye-zavisimosti-ubuntu

Comment: Вопрос решился после переустановки системы. Вообще говоря, если бы не эта ветка переписки, которая привела к сносу ОС, наврятли решение вообще бы нашлось. Так что всё супер. Спасибо!